# Will a folder's content still be counted toward Dropbox's quota if I move it out of \Dropbox folder?

Tags: synchronization, dropbox, quota

My home Dropbox folder is at ~\Dropbox. What happens if I move a few subfolders in there to some other folder, e.g ~. ? Will the moved folders still be synchronized and counted towards my quota?

I am exceeding my quota and finding a way to cut my usage down but don't want to remove anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the moved folders still be synchronized and counted towards my quota?

No

Moving ~\Dropbox\something to ~\something moves the folder something and its content out of your dropbox. As a result it will not longer be counted as part of your dropbox quota.